# ctypes: how to pass argument by pointer and read value in python

Tags: python, binding, ctypes

I have a c function which signature is:

```
bool f(double *a, double *b);
```

this function is compiled in a shared library lib.so

I am trying to wrap this function using ctypes.

Here what I have so far:

```
import ctypes 
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('lib.so')                                                                                      
lib.f.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))                                                                                                   

def f(a):                                                                                                                                                                                     
    global lib                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ctype_a = ctypes.c_double * len(a)                                                                                                                                                                    
    ctype_b = ctypes.c_double * 3                                                                                                                                                                           
    success = lib.f(ctype_a(*a), ctype_b(*[0,0,0]))                                                                                                                
    return success,ctype_b
```

This seems to work fine except than ctype_b is of class PyCArrayType, and I do not know how to read data from it.

Comment: You need to create an instance first, e.g. `b = ctype_b();` `return lib.f(ctype_a(*a), b), b`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `global lib`. If you don't assign to a name in a function, it's automatically nonlocal (for nested functions) or looked up in globals and builtins.